# Is it possible to return &String reference created and moved from a method?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I would like to have this kind of struct to save memory allocation:

```
pub struct MyStruct<'a> {
    corpus: HashSet<String>,
    names: HashMap<&'a String, u8>,
    // we may need some other properties such as addresses: HashMap<&'a String, u8> ...etc from corpus

}

impl MyStruct<'_> {
    pub fn new() -> MyStruct<'static> {
        let mut corpus = HashSet::new();
        corpus.insert("test".to_string());
        corpus.insert("test2".to_string());
        // insert more to the corpus...

        let mut names = HashMap::default();
        names.insert(corpus.get("test").unwrap(), 1);
        MyStruct {
            corpus,
            names,
        }
    }
}
```

I want to save memory usage of the `names` property by reusing the `corpus` that is created from the `new` method as in the example above. (The corpus and names might have about a few million names). Is it possible? or I must use `names: HashMap<String, u8>`.

This is the error of course:

```
102 |           names.insert(corpus.get("test").unwrap(), 1);
    |                        ------------------ `corpus` is borrowed here
103 | /         MyStruct {
104 | |             corpus,
105 | |             names,
106 | |         }
    | |_________^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
```

Comment: An alternative that may work for you is using `corpus: Vec<String>` and `name: HashMap<usize, u8>`. Checking whether a word is in the corpus will be O(log n) if you sort the vector, which is still fast enough for many use cases.

Comment: If your corpus doesn't change at runtime, you can also simply create a static instance of it, e.g. using `lazy_static`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks. The lazy static may be the way to go. Anyways, I am looking for a better method instead of lazy_static.

Comment: You can also separate the corpus from `MyStruct`, and pass a reference to the corpus when `MyStruct` is constructed. Then you are storing the owned data and the references in different structs.